# c# nested gridview display below each outer gridview row without expand collapse

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have seen a lot of examples of displaying a nested gridview below the outer gridview row by using expand/collapse with javascript.  Is there a way to display the nested gridview below each outer gridview row without using javascript expand collapse?

Comment: Wouldn't you just follow the same tutorial, but leave out the javascript?

Comment: How would that work? Can you give an example?

Comment: In the examples that I have seen, the javascript is what shifts the display of the nested gridview to be below the outer gridview row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of the other tutorials and the solution is the following.

Add the following code before the nested gridview:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit1" Text="<tr id='trGrid'><td colspan='4'" />
```

Add the following code after the nested gridview:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit2" Text="</td></tr>" />
```

Modify the colspan definition to meet your needs.

This solution creates an extra column in the gridview row above the nested gridview.